# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] issue on cross domain

Tags: php, http, https, cross-domain, http-referer

I am having problem with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. I need to check its value to execute some script. Some other website with "https" is redirecting the user to my website via "http". But due to "https" to "http" redirection i am not getting any HTTP_REFERER. My website also has "https" ssl but they are using static links (of my website) on their website, so its not easy for them to replace those. I know referer depends on browser and security purpose but is there any alternative way to get this?

Comment: Everything that _relies_ on a referrer, is broken by design.

Comment: _“but they are using static links (of my website) on their website, so its not easy for them to replace those”_ - a small JavaScript that goes through the links and replaces `http` with `https` when they point to your domain could be an easy “fix” for that.

Comment: @misorude thanks for your suggestion. But they have already refused to do this. I am looking for any alternate solution to achieve this.

Comment: Without them actively taking part, I don’t think there is any way to fix this. They are in charge of instructing browsers how to handle sending of a referrer for outgoing links on their page. (This would probably need `Referrer-Policy: unsafe-url`, to not lose the referrer when going from HTTPS to HTTP. That would either have to be set globally - or added as an attribute to the individual links, which you already said was not an option.)